# Sarah's beauty at 80

Tags: sources-mekorot, abraham, sarah, beauty

Shalom u bracha. Does anybody know the source of a midrash that says that Pharaoh (and everybody) finds Sarah really beautiful even at her 80's because Avraham gave her so much confidence by repeating her all the time how beautiful she was: so she really trust it and she "transmitted" that confidence to the world indeed.
(I found this comment in a Harold Kushner's book he just quotes: "It is written in the Midrash". It is very interesting what he says I just wanted to make it kosher and add the source)

Comment: Sounds very postmodern. If anything Chazzal say that he never noticed her beauty until that first time on the way to Mitzraim, which was accidental.

Comment: Eric Bern uses the very nice phrase "the beauty of a woman in whom is reflected the love of her husband." I think that may be a more appropriate biblical analysis. But I do not think you will find a source in the medrash for the statement quoted.

Comment: There are sources for people's belief in things being effective. For example Rb Chaim Shmuelevitz illustrated from sources in the gemara that belief can empower even an inanimate object or an animal, all the more so a person. However there is no source that I am aware of that such belief can change the physical constitution of a thing.

Comment: As an aside to the previous comment from Berne, Rb Elya Lopian says that Sarah's beauty was the beauty of grace, simplicity, purity and naivete, not that of a fashion model.

Comment: I always feel sorry for women who are not naturally attractive who are born into a society that lays an emphasis on physical attractiveness and who then go around dressing themselves up to make up for what they perceive to be an innate shortcoming. Something tragic about that...

Comment: Thanks THE GRAPKE! Chazak u Baruch!!!